# How to convert a LINQ query result to a DataTable dynamically?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, datatable, lambda

How to convert a LINQ query result to a DataTable dynamically?

There are solutions where you create another class and specify the column names, but I want the flexibility to change the LINQ structure like column names, column quantities, and have a DataTable generated with the columns names automatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've included an extension method that I use with SqlBulkCopy that should do the job, but I'd like to ask why you want to this conversion.  There are a very limited number of cases (SqlBulkCopy being one) where a list of objects can't do everything a datatable can.  You can use them as binding sources for most controls ... just curious.

```
public static DataTable toDataTable<T>(this IEnumerable<T> value, List<string> exclusionList)
        where T : class
    {
        var dataTable = new DataTable();

        var type = typeof(T);

        var properties = type.GetProperties().Where(x =>  !exclusionList.Contains(x.Name)).ToList();

        foreach (var propertyInfo in properties)
        {
            var propertyType = propertyInfo.PropertyType;
            if (!propertyType.IsScalar())
                continue;

            var nullableType = Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(propertyType);
            propertyType = nullableType ?? propertyType;

            var dataColumn = new DataColumn(propertyInfo.Name, propertyType);

            if (nullableType != null)
                dataColumn.AllowDBNull = true;

            dataTable.Columns.Add(dataColumn);
        }

        foreach (var row in value)
        {
            var dataRow = dataTable.NewRow();

            foreach (var property in properties)
            {
                var safeValue = property.GetValue(row, null) ?? DBNull.Value;                    
                dataRow[property.Name] = safeValue;
            }

            dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow);
        }

        return dataTable;
    }
```

Comment: Let's suppose you have a Class on a Library that retrieves information from the DataBase using LINQ, you want to return the results so different kind of projects like Windows Form (DataGridView), Web Form (GridView) can display the information, you can't return a list of Anonymous types. I tried to use your extension but I don't know where IsScalar() is declared.

Comment: Is scalar is in another library, you can pull that out

Answer (score 1):

Look into the [MoreLinq](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) Nuget package. It has a function `ToDataTable()`

```
var LinqResults = from ......;
DataTable dt_Results = LinqResults.ToDataTable();
```

https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/

It has other VERY useful functions as well:
https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/wiki/OperatorsOverview

Answer (score 0):

They key is to use the LINQ query result as its Implemented IList interface.
If you receive the result as a parameter on a method as an IList object, you can access its columns and rows, this way:

```
var props = item.GetType().GetProperties();
```

Refer to this example, it's a small class which please note the it just abstracts the creation of the DataTable, and there is a static method inside called "LINQToDataTable" which you should use.

1. Step 1, create a class called "GridHelper" (uses System.Data for DataTable structure)

   ```
   public class GridHelper
   {
   private DataTable baseDt;

   public GridHelper(string tableName)
   {
       baseDt = new DataTable(tableName);
   }


   public DataTable getDataTable()
   {
       return baseDt;
   }

   public object[,] getObjToFill()
   {
       object[,] obj = new object[baseDt.Columns.Count, 2];
       for (int i = 0; i < baseDt.Columns.Count; i++)
       {
           obj[i, 0] = baseDt.Columns[i].ColumnName;
       }

       return obj;
   }

   public void addColumn(string colName, Type valueType)
   {
       baseDt.Columns.Add(colName, valueType);
   }

   public void addRow(object[,] values)
   {

       DataRow newRow = baseDt.NewRow();

       for (int i = 0; i < values.Length / 2; i++)
       {
           bool colFound = false;

           for (int j = 0; j < baseDt.Columns.Count; j++)
           {
               if (baseDt.Columns[j].ColumnName == values[i, 0].ToString())
               {
                   colFound = true;
                   break;
               }
           }
           if (colFound == false)
           {
               throw new Exception("The column " + values[i, 0].ToString() + " has not been added yet.");
           }

           newRow[values[i, 0].ToString()] = values[i, 1];
       }

       baseDt.Rows.Add(newRow);

   }


   public static DataTable LINQToDataTable<T>(T objToList) where T : System.Collections.IList
   {


       GridHelper ghResult = new GridHelper("Report");


       foreach (Object item in objToList)
       {
           var props = item.GetType().GetProperties();

           foreach (var prop in props)
           {
               ghResult.addColumn(prop.Name, typeof(string));
               //prop.Name
               //prop.GetValue(item)
           }

           break;
       }

       object[,] obj = ghResult.getObjToFill();




       foreach (Object item in objToList)
       {
           var props = item.GetType().GetProperties();
           int index = 0;
           foreach (var prop in props)
           {
               //ReportValue(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(item, null));
               //prop.Name
               obj[index, 1] = prop.GetValue(item);
               index++;
           }

           ghResult.addRow(obj);
       }


       return ghResult.getDataTable();
   }



   }
   ```
2. Usage:

   ```
       var listaReporte =
           (from t in dbContext.TablaPruebas
            select new
            {
                Name = t.name,
                Score = t.score
            }
           ) .ToList();

       DataTable dt = Library.GridHelper.LINQToDataTable(listaReporte);
   ```
3. And that is, use your DataTable as you wish, on a GridView or DataGridView